# Why does extracting a specific git tag to a /tmp directory mess up the working tree?

Tags: git

Because I wanted to look at the files in the last release, tagged `v2.1`, to run it in isolation from my working directory, I created a `tmp` directory

```
mkdir /tmp/lastRelease
```

and extracted the last release in that directory

```
git --work-tree=/tmp/lastRelease checkout tags/v2.1 -- .
```

The files are indeed extracted just fine to `/tmp/lastRelease`.

But now when I run `git status` in the working directory I find that very many files (all the files modified since tag v2.1?) appear as staged for commit, and another long list of files (that are in HEAD) appears as *not* staged for commit.

Was this last command the right way to extract a specific tag? How do I reset to HEAD? (The obvious `git checkout HEAD` doesn't modify what `git status` says, even though the files are there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't (do anything to your current *working tree*).  What it does effectively damage / mess-up is the (singular) *index*.  (It also will affect `HEAD`.)

Each non-bare Git repository has one working tree, one index, and one `HEAD`.  That one index is used by `git checkout` or `git switch`; that one `HEAD` is set by it.  When you run:

```
git --work-tree=<path> checkout ...
```

your Git extracts the specified commit—the `...` part—and writes it *through the index* into the working tree.

Normally, the working tree to which your `git checkout` or `git switch` would write is *the* (singular) working tree.  But with `--work-tree` you temporarily override *that* one working tree with one *different* working tree—so *that* is the working tree to which this Git operation writes.  But you have not changed the (singular) index, nor the (singular) `HEAD`, and `git checkout` or `git switch` will write to those as well.

The `HEAD` keeps track of the *current commit* by containing:

- a raw hash ID, or
- the name of the current branch (with the branch name itself then containing the commit hash ID).

The index holds your *proposed next commit*, which starts out matching the current commit—so that when you switch commits, Git first removes the existing checked-out commit's files (as recorded in the index and stored in the existing in the working tree), and then plugs in the target commit's files (to the index and working tree).  Using `--work-tree` to re-point the working tree, without first cleaning out and removing the *current* working tree and index, leaves them out of sync.

If you don't mind the effect on `HEAD`, and are otherwise using this `git checkout` or `git switch` for a special purpose, consider setting `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to the name of a temporary file that does not exist now, and that you will delete once the `git checkout` or `git switch` finishes.

If you *do* mind the effect on `HEAD`, or intend to do this for more general purposes, consider not using `git --work-tree checkout` like this at all: instead, make sure your Git is at least 2.15, and begin using `git worktree`.  See [the `git worktree` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for more about `git worktree`.  **Edit:** Or, as [jthill notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71074696/1256452), use `git archive` to build an archive you can extract without disturbing the working tree (note that this is a bit different, especially if there are `.gitattributes` rules for archive-building in the tag you'll be extracting).

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer. I don't know why the working directory gets messed up when extracting to an unrelated directory, but it's possible to return to a sane state—the one where the repo was just before the `git --work-tree...` command—by running:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wanted to do was either

```
git archive v2.1 | tar Cx /path/to/tmp/tree
```

or

```
git worktree add /path/to/tmp/tree v2.1
```

or

```
git clone -sb v2.3 . /path/to/tmp/tree
```

or even

```
scratch=`mktemp -d`
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$PWD/.git/scratch-index git --work-tree=$scratch read-tree -um v2.1
```

because as @torek points out `git checkout` is a convenience command, built for "standard" workflows where your work trees are for content you're actively tracking; the index is Git's manifest for what you last checked out or added there, and `HEAD` is its ancestor commit.